# Pen Drive Not detected in Linux

Tags: linux, usb-drive

I inserted a new pendrive. The following is the dmesg output:

```
[127321.248105] usb 2-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 9    
[127321.380898] scsi11 : usb-storage 2-2:1.0    
[127322.381159] scsi 11:0:0:0: Direct-Access     XXXXXXXX U1170CONTROLLER  0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2    
[127322.384481] sd 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0    
[127322.387127] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

But after executing the `fdisk -l` there is no device showing /dev/sdb

Following is the output of fdisk command:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System    

   /dev/sda1   *           1       19103   153443296    7  HPFS/NTFS    
   /dev/sda2           19103       34764   125794300    7  HPFS/NTFS    
   /dev/sda3           34764       38914    33333249    5  Extended    
   /dev/sda5           34764       34776       97280   83  Linux    
   /dev/sda6           34776       35025     1998848   82  Linux swap / Solaris    
   /dev/sda7           35025       38914    31235072   83  Linux    `
```

Can somebody please tell me how to debug this problem ?

**Edit:** 
*There is one sdb created in the /dev directory after inserting the usb drive.*

On executing the the following command I am getting the output as:

```
root@pradeep-laptop:~# mount /dev/sdb /mnt
mount: /dev/sdb: unknown device
```

Here is the output of `lsusb` command :

```
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0a5c:2101 Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth Controller
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 048d:1170 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The Line `Bus 001 Device 007: ID 048d:1170 Integrated Technology Express, Inc.` was added after inserting the pen drive.

[image: Here is the error which I received while creating partition table using gparted]

Comment: You can usually find your attached drives (assuming they have a label) under `/dev/disk/by-label/` or otherwise `/dev/disk/by-uuid` which is more reliable. To see what `UUID` corresponds to your drive use the `blkid` command. Do you find it? What's output of `lsblk`?

Comment: Is `/dev/sdb` created automatically? Maybe the usb pen drive is not formatted yet. BTW, generally it could be helpful to add small information about the Linux distribution and the kernel you use.

Comment: My Linux Kernel is: 2.6.35-22-generic and I am using Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: @jofel: Yes the /dev/sdb is created. I think the usb pen drive is not formatted yet. Can you tell me how to format it in Linux

Comment: If you run `lsUSB` you will get a very strange output of all the things hooked into your USB ports. Some are obvious (or normally are such as the mouse etc). Post the output, which gives info on the type and product ID, and we can tell you what you need to search for on google so as you can use your drive. The other thing to do is to run the command before and after plugging in the drive; that way you can be sure it is being recognised by the OS.

Comment: @DaveM I have added the output of `lsusb` command also. Can you suggest me what to do next.

Comment: Is this a new pendrive, a pendrive known to be formatted with files but never used under linux or a pendrive that was working under linux before?

Comment: @njsg This one is the new pendrive, ordered from letsbuy.com. It is neither working in windows nor in linux.

Comment: Then you have to consider the possibility that either you got a nonstandard pendrive or that the pendrive is somehow damaged/broken. Formatting it, with or without partition table, should be just a breeze, at least under GNU/Linux, provided proper drivers have been compiled either in the kernel or as modules (the disk is recognized as a "SCSI removable disk" -- I'm not an expert, but I think either that's enough or close to enough). There should be no "no medium found" errors. If it starts getting harder, before pushing too hard check if the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make at least one file system on the pendrive (and a partition table, certainly). The first file system you make should be the `/dev/sdb1` which is then mountable. For example:

```
root# mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb1 && mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt -t auto
```

will run.

Of course, you could add more than one file system to the pendrive, their name will be `/dev/sdb{1,2..n}`, respectively. Editing storage devices with `gparted` would make the process easier by visibility.

Comment: Actually, it's pretty common (and annoying) to see pendrives which do *not* have a partition table, and where `/dev/sdb` would be the filesystem itself.

Comment: I doubt that `mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb` creates any partition table which results in getting `/dev/sdb1`. Either have no partition table and mount then `/dev/sdb` or create a partition table using e.g. `fdisk` or `gpartet` and then run the mkfs on `/dev/sdb1` not on /dev/sdb otherwise you would overwrite the partition table. As usb pen drives are normally used to share data between computers, widely supported filesystems like FAT32 (`mkfs.vfat -F32 /dev/sdb1`) can be helpful.

Comment: @jofel: I tried to create partition table by both `fdisk and gparted` but I am getting the error `Unable to open /dev/sdb`. Can you please tell me what I can try ?

Comment: @pradeepchhetri you need to be root to accessing `/dev/sdb`. Use `sudo`.

Comment: @jofel No, I am doing from root only.

Comment: @pradeepchhetri Check if it is still /dev/sdb - this could change to /dev/sdc etc. if you re-plug the pen drive. But since the possibility that the sell unformatted drives is very low and you cannot read the pen drive even with Windows, I suppose that its hardware is faulty - exchange the pen drive.

Comment: @jofel it is still /dev/sdb. whether it needs hardware level formatting..isn't there any solution to this kind of problem.

Comment: @pradeepchhetri, once I had a pen that was corrupted and giving trouble, so I cleared it with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX &` (where `X` is the letter referring to the pen, **without** the partition number). Then I used `gdisk` to make the partition table, formatted the partitions, and it worked. Maybe you should try clearing it this way.